# How to check HPE StorageWorks MSA60 health disk

Tags: storage, hp-storageworks

I have an HP Dl380 g6 with Windows server 2019 and the storage is an MSA60. I use a Smart Arrey P800 card for the MSA60.

Is there any windows HP software that I can check the disks health? Or I need to restart the server and enter theP800 controller.

Th

Comment: That server went end of support over six years ago, the MSA was 5.5 years ago - neither support Server 2019 - this site is for professionals, who wouldn't use kit that far out of support, please consider this if you ever post again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, please use the [Smart Storage Administrator utility](https://support.hpe.com/connect/s/product?language=en_US&tab=driversAndSoftware&kmpmoid=5409145#t=DriversandSoftware).

This will allow you to check the health and alter the MSA and P800 controller configuration from the Windows OS.

Comment: Thank your, perfect.